# How can I use className in component from styled-components in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

**NavStyles.js**

import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Nav = styled.nav`width: 100%;`   ;

export const NavMenuMobile = styled.ul`

```
    height: 80px;

    .navbar_list_class {
        font-size: 2rem;
        background-color: red;
    }   
      
    ${props => props.navbar_list_props && `  
        font-size: 2rem;
        background-color: gray;
    `}
```

`;

**Navbar.js**
import React from 'react'
import {Nav, NavMenuMobile} from "./NavStyles";

const Navbar = () => {

```
return (
    <Nav>
        {/* work no problem */}
        <NavMenuMobile navbar_list_props>Nav Bar props</NavMenuMobile>

        {/* not work How to use..? */} 
        <NavMenuMobile className="navbar_list_class">Nav Bar class</NavMenuMobile>
    </Nav>
)
```

}

export default Navbar

Answer (score 0):

```
<Nav>
    <NavMenuMobile className={navbar_list_props}>Nav Bar props</NavMenuMobile>
</Nav>
```

Try This

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting styles for the children within NavMenuMobile with the class "navbar_list_class".

Should work with &.navbar_list_class

```
export const NavMenuMobile = styled.ul`
  height: 80px;

  &.navbar_list_class {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: red;
  }   
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want childrens to be styled you can use following code :

```
<Nav>
        {/* work no problem */}
        <NavMenuMobile navbar_list_props>Nav Bar props</NavMenuMobile>

        {/* code updated here */}
        <NavMenuMobile navbar_list_props>
            Nav Bar class
            <ul className="navbar_list_class">Nav Bar list class</ul>
        </NavMenuMobile>
</Nav>
```

but remember this will style both the class i.e. the props style that you have passed as well as the style of ".navbar_list_class", rather you can remove the props style or  make conditional style in ".navbar_list_class" itself.

although this might not be the most idiomatic or best approach.